# .tmux.conf not working

Tags: bash, configuration, tmux

I have recently installed Tmux and I cannot get anything I put in `.tmux.conf` to work.

I have the file in my home directory, with a call to it in `.bash_profile` (it would not even read it otherwise). But whatever I do every command gets a Bash error, I have tried:

```
:set -g status-fg green
:set -g status-fg black

tmux set -g status-fg green
tmux set -g status-fg black

set -g status-fg green
set -g status-fg black
```

Every time, I get an error along the lines of `bash: (command) not found`.

I am most likely overlooking something but help would be appreciated.

(The errors I am getting) (Using the commands with no prefix, just there names)

```
-bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
-bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
-bash: unbind: command not found
-bash: unbind: command not found
-bash: bind-key: command not found
-bash: unbind: command not found
-bash: /home/gizmoz/.tmux.conf: line 28: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /home/gizmoz/.tmux.conf: line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: You shouldn't need any reference to tmux in your `.bash_profile`. Remove it. Do things properly. That lind of insertion can only cause trouble down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to read `~/.tmux.conf` from your shell's startup files. It's is not a shell script.

The commands in `~/.tmux.conf` are `tmux` commands that `tmux` will read when it starts up.  They are not shell commands.  This is why your shell complains when it tries to read it.

What you want in that file is

```
set -g status-fg green
set -g status-fg black
```

The commands that you show prefixed by `:` is what you type in to interactively set the options inside a `tmux` session, after pressing the current prefix key combo.

The commands that you show prefixed by `tmux` could be given at the shell prompt inside a `tmux` session to interactive set the options.

As a side note, there seems to possibly be unbalanced quoting in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, based on the last errors that your shell spits out.  This may possibly give you issues even if you don't read the file from your `~/.bash_profile` file, so you should investigate that.